# Не работает мышь в Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

Возникла непонятная проблема с Android Studio. Отсутствует реакция на мышь, то есть нельзя мышью нажать ни на какой элемент. Кнопки не реагируют на нажатия мыши в первом же окне в дизайне Android Studio после его установки. При клике по окну оно получает фокус и можно работать с элементами окна при помощи клавиатуры, но на наведение и клики мыши никакой реакции. Это единственное приложение, в котором есть такая проблема. Я раньше немного работал с Android Studio на этом компьютере, но в какой-то момент перестала работать мышь. Определить возможное новое ПО, которое могло повлиять не удаётся, так как Android Studio запускал редко.

Что пробовал делать: проверять на вирусы, менять мышь и клавиатуру, отключать все другие USB устройства, полностью удалять и заново ставить разные версии Android Studio. Наконец, для проведения максимально чистого эксперимента убрал из компьютера все жесткие диски, поставил новый чистый и установил на него другую версию Windows. Сразу после этого - Android Studio. Мышь не работает. Как так? Железная проблема? Что посоветуете делать?

Основа компьютера - AMD Athlon X4 860K на A88XM-A, если это может влиять.

Comment: А можно видео посмотреть, как это происходит о_0?

Comment: Alex_Skvortsov, вы волшебник! Не представляете, сколько всего я перепробовал и сколько дней убил на поиск решения проблемы. Установил сейчас FastStone Capture, чтобы записать с экрана, стал записывать ролик - а всё работает! Просто нет слов. Позже поэкспериментирую, что будет после перезагрузки. Абсолютно непонятно, что произошло и будет ли эффект стабильным, посмотрим. Тем не менее, спасибо, что подтолкнули к таким действиям.

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov, к сожалению, после перезагрузки компьютера всё снова перестало работать, так что видео записал. Если нужно что-то ещё конкретное попробовать сделать - говорите, не стесняйтесь, я уже на всё готов... Однако, сам факт, что из-за чего-то один раз студия начала откликаться на мышь очень  интересен. Из-за чего - непонятно.
https://youtu.be/VbUp-LmW7gE

Comment: Я впервые такое вижу. Попробуйте удалить AS и заново поставить следуя этой [инструкции](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/9-urok-2-ustanovka-i-nastrojka-sredy-razrabotki.html) в точности. И проверьте, что у Вас с другими java приложениями?

Comment: Попробовал переустановить еще раз - а вдруг... Не помогло. А какие еще java приложения попробовать, например?

Comment: Да можно вообще просто PyCharm поставить от тех же Intelij.

Comment: PyCharm - так же не работает...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Помогла замена мыши на PS/2...

Comment: Надо же как бывает...